Unable to verify message from signature
Sign verifier.m
This file has the utility to verify the data
#import "SignatureVerifier.h"
#include \<Foundation/Foundation.h\>
#import \<CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h\>

@implementation SignatureVerifier

- (BOOL)verifySignature:(NSString \*)jsonString
  signature:(NSData \*)signatureData
  publicKey:(SecKeyRef)publicKey
  hashFunction:(NSString \*)hashFunction {

  // Validate input parameters
  if (!jsonString || !signatureData || !publicKey) {
  NSLog(@"Error: Invalid input parameters");
  return NO;
  }

  // Convert the JSON string to data (normalize if necessary)
  NSData \*jsonData = \[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding\];
  NSLog(@"Json Data utf8: %@", jsonData);
  if (!jsonData) {
  NSLog(@"Error converting JSON string to data");
  return NO;
  }

  // Hash the JSON data using SHA256
  NSData \*hashedData = nil;
  if (\[hashFunction isEqualToString:@"SHA256"\]) {
  hashedData = \[self sha256HashForData:jsonData\];
  NSLog(@"Hashed Data: %@", hashedData);
  } else {
  NSLog(@"Unsupported hash function: %@", hashFunction);
  return NO;
  }

  if (!hashedData) {
  NSLog(@"Error: Hashing failed");
  return NO;
  }

  // Verify the signature
  CFErrorRef error = NULL;
  BOOL result = SecKeyVerifySignature(
  publicKey,
  kSecKeyAlgorithmRSASignatureMessagePKCS1v15SHA256,
  (\__bridge CFDataRef) hashedData,
  (\__bridge CFDataRef) signatureData,
  &error
  );

  if (!result || error) {
  if (error) {
  CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
  NSLog(@"Error verifying signature: %@", errorDescription);
  CFRelease(errorDescription);
  }
  return NO;
  }

  NSLog(@"Signature successfully verified.");
  return YES;
  }

- (NSData \*)sha256HashForData:(NSData \*)data {
  if (!data) {
  NSLog(@"Error: No data provided for hashing");
  return nil;
  }

  uint8_t hash\[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH\];
  CC_SHA256(data.bytes, (CC_LONG)data.length, hash);

  return \[NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH\];
  }

@end

main.m
This is the main file using the utility.
Please consider the other utility function correct as they've been checked.

#import \<Foundation/Foundation.h\>
#import "JSONREADER.m"
#import "KeyReader.h"
#import "SignatureVerifier.h"
#import "hex_to_data.h"

int main(int argc, const char \* argv\[\]) {
@autoreleasepool {

        // Create an instance of KeyReader
        KeyReader *keyReader = [[KeyReader alloc] init]; 
    
        // Reading public key file 
        NSString *keyFilePath = @"./crl_verify.key";
        SecKeyRef publicKey = [keyReader publicKeyFromKeyFile:keyFilePath];
        
        if (publicKey) {
            NSLog(@"Public key successfully created");
            // CFRelease(publicKey);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create public key");
        }
    
        JSONReader *jsonReader = [[JSONReader alloc] init];
        
        // Reading crl json file
        NSString *filePath = @"./crl.json";
        
        NSError *json_read_error = nil;
        NSDictionary *jsonContent = nil;
        jsonContent = [jsonReader readJSONFromFile:filePath error:&json_read_error];
        
        if (jsonContent) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully read JSON: %@", jsonContent);
            
            // Example: Accessing a value in the JSON dictionary
            NSString *signature = jsonContent[@"signature"];
            NSLog(@"Value for 'key': %@", signature);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [json_read_error localizedDescription]);
        }
    
        // Read tbs_cert_list
        NSError *json_convert_error = nil;
        NSString *jsonString = jsonContent[@"tbs_cert_list"];
        NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                          options:0
                                                            error:&json_convert_error];
    
        if (json_convert_error) {
            NSLog(@"Error deserializing JSON: %@", [json_convert_error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"tbs_cert_list JSON Dictionary: %@", jsonDict);
        }
        NSString *signature = jsonContent[@"signature"];
        NSLog(@"Hex Sign: %@", signature);
        
        NSData *data = [HexUtils dataFromHexString: signature];
        NSLog(@"hex_to_sign_data: %@", data);
    
        // NSData *signatureData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:data options:0];
        NSString *signatureData = [HexUtils base64StringFromHexString: signature];
        NSLog(@"Base64 Encoded String: %@", signatureData);
    
        // Print parameters
        NSLog(@"Verifying signature with the following parameters:");
        NSLog(@"JSON String: %@", jsonString);
        NSLog(@"Signature Data: %@", signatureData);
        NSLog(@"Public Key: %@", publicKey);
        NSLog(@"Hash Function: %@", @"SHA256");
    
        // Instantiate SignatureVerifier``your text``
        SignatureVerifier *verifier = [[SignatureVerifier alloc] init];
        BOOL verified = [verifier verifySignature:jsonString
                                        signature:data
                                        publicKey:publicKey
                                     hashFunction:@"SHA256"];
        
        if (verified) {
            NSLog(@"Signature is valid!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Signature verification failed.");
        }
    
        // Release public key
        CFRelease(publicKey);
        
    }
    return 0;

}

So I've verified the data using openssl and a python program which is working fine.
But I can not verify it in this program. What am I doing wrong ?
This returns a failure in verification. However, it should verify the data.
The formats and types seems fine as per apple document.


Please include at least the openssl commands you used for verifying.
